# Possible to create a multi-selection List with value-based NavigationLink in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app that includes an asset manager that allows users to import and edit custom assets. When browsing available assets, users can choose to view the assets in a `List` view that is populated by a `SectionedFetchRequest`. Each row of the list is a `NavigationLink` that presents a detail view for the asset that the user tapped on. I've got all of this working nicely so far.

The issue I'm running into now is adding multi-select support to the list so users can select and modify multiple assets at once. Specifically, when I use `List(_:selection:rowContent:)` with `NavigationLink(_:value:)`, the navigation links no longer present detail views. However, using `NavigationLink(_:destination:)` instead works as expected -- the navigation links present detail views *and* the list supports multi-select.

Is this a known bug or is there something else I'm missing? I've tried finding information on this, but have come up short.

Below is a very simplified example of what I'm trying to accomplish and does not work as expected. I'm expecting the navigation links to present detail views, but they do not. Rows can be tapped on and selected, but the detail view does not present.

```swift
struct TestView: View {

    let fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]
    
    @State private var selection: Set<String> = Set()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(fruits, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { fruit in
                NavigationLink(fruit, value: fruit)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { string in
                Text(string)
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here's a simplified example of the code that does work as expected.

```swift
struct TestView: View {

    let fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]
    
    @State private var selection: Set<String> = Set()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(fruits, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { fruit in
                NavigationLink(fruit) {
                    Text(fruit)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `NavigationLink(_:destination:)`?

Comment: @Sweeper The value-based `NavigationLink` initializer is newer and has certain advantages, one for instance being that the view is declared in the `navigationDestination` closure, i.e. it is only initialized when being used, while the old `NavigationLink` initializes all destination views immediately when the list renders, which can be quite expensive and might cause laggy scrolling.